# Why does a deque constructed from a single list return its item rather than the list itself?

Tags: python, deque

I run the code below:

```
from collections import deque
q = deque([('0000',0)])
a = q.popleft()

print(a)
print(type(a))

b = [('0000',0)]

print(b)
print(type(b))
```

And output is:

```
('0000', 0)
<class 'tuple'>
[('0000', 0)]
<class 'list'>
```

I wonder why type of `a` is `tuple`, but `b` is `list`. I expected `q.popleft()` to return `[('0000', 0)]`.

Comment: so popLeft returns the element in the list ,which is a tuple , while b is a list itself,

Comment: `deque` itself is something like a list, the code isn't much different from `q = [(...)]; a = q[0]`…

Comment: Maybe `[('0000',0)]` is "same input" but you are processing it in different ways.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`deque`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque) aceepts an iterable as its argument. It then unpacks that iterable to get the elements to fill the deque.

ie, if you pass

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

to `deque` as

```
q = deque([1, 2, 3])
```

the deque will have `1`, `2` and `3` as its elements. Not `[1, 2, 3]`

(it follows that, you cannot initialize a `deque` with multiple arguments to be used as its elements.)

If you think of `deque` as only a list,

`deque([1,2,3])` is equivalent to the list `[1,2,3]`, not `[[1, 2, 3]]`. For it be equivalent to `[[1, 2, 3]]`, you would have to call `deque([[1,2,3]])`

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you've got two collections, a `deque` called `q` and a `list` called `b`. Both of these collections contain a single element, a tuple `('0000',0)`.

When you defined `a`, you popped that element out of `q`, so `a` is only the tuple.
You didn't perform a similar operation on `b`, however. Something analogous might be

```
c = b.pop()
```

in which case, `c` is a tuple.

Answer (score 2):

`a` is a tuple because its values are enclosed in round brackets `(` `)`, while b is a list of tuples, as in contains the tuple `('0000', 0)` inside square brackets `[` `]`.

In order to have both variables as tuple, you would need to rewrite b as follows:

```
b = ('0000',0)
```

`deque` takes in an iterable like `list`, `strings`, etc. and creates a double-ended queue of it. So now, your list has transformed into a de-queue. And when you invoke the `popleft()` method on a `deque` object, it removes the first element from the queue and returns it. In this case, the item was ('0000', 0). Hence, the type of the item is logged as a `tuple`.

In second scenario, you are printing the type of a variable that holds a `list` of `tuple`s.

Answer (score 1):

I thought that when I create a deque `q = deque([('0000',0)])`, the first element is `[('0000',0)]`.

Now, I realize that when I create a queue like this, the first element is `('0000',0)`

And I can init deque with lots of element like `q = deque([('0000',0),('0002',0)])`

Comment: I think it's the way you initialize the `deque`: it takes a list of initial elements. So the pair of brackes ( `[` and `]` ) is "consumed" by the `deque` initialization.

Comment: Well a quick look in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque) will show that the signature is `deque([iterable[, maxlen]])` and it states: *Returns a new deque object initialized left-to-right (using append()) with data from iterable.*